# Need help to intuitively understand how Gradient Ascent will work with a specific example shared herewith.

Tags: partial-derivative, gradient-descent

I am unable to imagine why the vector created by partial derivatives should always point to the steepest ascent. **I want to give an example to justify my concern.**

Suppose you are standing at 0,0 position. There are smooth slopes at x and y axis with a slope of 1 each. But these slopes are very narrow and the rest of the field is flat. So for example (0.1,1) will be flat but (0,1) will have a slope of 1. Similarly (1,0.1) will be flat but (1,0) will have a slope of 1. So the path of steepest ascent are either on the x axis or on the y axis. But when you calculate the vector it comes out to be at 45 degree angle since both the partial derivatives with respect to x and y are exactly the same. What am I doing wrong here?

Note: I am new to vectors and partial derivatives. I have not been able to formulate any equation that gives the kind of curve I have described above. Probably once I have such an equation, I will be able to see where I am going wrong. I know there is some misconception on my part that is creating this scenario. I would like to know what that error is and how partial derivatives will give us a right answer in the example that I have given.

Comment: Keep in mind that the direction of steepest descent is relative to a specific point. When you move, even slightly, from that point, the direction will not be the same (in general).

Comment: I agree. But shouldn't it give the direction of highest ascent at every point? If it should then why does it seem to be not working in the highlighted example?

Comment: I don't see any problem in your example... the point (1,0) is far from (0,0) why do you think that there should exist any relation between the direction od steepest ascent at (0,0) and (1,0)?

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding. The slope begins from the point (0,0) itself and moves along both the x axis and the y axis. It is a narrow slope and as soon as you move away from the axis, you land on the x-y plane. So for example when you are at at the point (1,0), you will be at a height of 1 unit. But as soon as you move to the point (1,0.1), you will be at the height 0.